# При инкременте переменной она принимает абсурдное значение

Tags: c++

Изучаю C++. Сейчас прохожу ООП, в задании нужно работать с динамической памятью.
Проблема такая, когда я инкрементирую переменную вот так:
`this->a[this->index++] == &aa;`, `this->index` становится равна числам вроде 6422016, 6422048 etc.
Когда же я делаю вот так:
`this->index++; this->a[this->index - 1] = &aa;` с переменной всё нормально.
С чём это связано?

Компилятор: MINGW 3.3
ОС: win10
CMake: 3.6.2
GDB: 7.8

Код задания:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Date {
    int year;
public:
    Date(int y): year(y) {}
    ~Date() { cout << "Date destructor" << endl; }

    void setDate(int y) { this->year = y; }
    int getYear() { return this->year; }

};

class A{
    Date date;
public:
    A(Date& d): date(d) {}

    void setDate(Date& d) { this->date = d; }
    Date* getDate();
};

Date* A::getDate() {
    Date* new_date = &this->date;
    return new_date;
}

class B {
    A *a[];
    int index = 0;
public:
    ~B() { delete[] a; }

    void addA(A& aa) { this->a[this->index++] = &aa; } // Не работает
    void func(int);
    void func2(int);
};

void B::func(int year) {
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->index; i++) {
        cout << i << endl;
        if(this->a[i]->getDate()->getYear() == year) {
            cout << "Yes " << year << endl;
            counter = i;
        }
    }

    func2(counter);
}

void B::func2(int a) {
    cout << this->a[a]->getDate()->getYear() << endl;
}

int main() {
   Date d(2000);
   A a(d), c(d);
   B b;

   b.addA(a);
   b.addA(c);

   b.func(2000);

   return 0;
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ**

> код, приведенный ниже может вызвать рвотные рефлексы и страшное желание минусовать, не читая. Воздержитесь!

---

> каждый раз, когда хочется сделать массив через `new[]`, следует подумать, может все таки использовать `std::vector`?

---

> код, приведенный ниже следует применять только для удоволетворения преподавателя, что бы получить зачет, если все остальное уже не работает.

Конструкция вида `A *a[];` может скомпилироваться, но только gcc. Называется эта штука [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). И хотя она не по стандарту, но gcc умеет закрывать глаза.

Итак, заставим это работать:)

Первое, что нужно сделать - это перенести объявление массива в конец класса. То есть, вместо

```
class B {
    A *a[];
    int index = 0;
public:
```

надо писать так

```
class B {
    int index = 0;
    A *a[];
public:
```

а лучше приватную секцию совсем в конец унести.

Также следует удалить в деструкторе удаление памяти. В нашем случае убрать вызов `delete` здесь (можно вообще удалить этот деструктор).

```
~B() { delete[] a; }
```

Теперь нужно ещё так сделать, что бы под класс B выделить достаточно памяти. Воспользуемся штукой placement new. Теперь main будет такой

```
int main() {
   Date d(2000);
   A a(d), c(d);
   // выделим буфер, размер взят заведомо большой
   char *buf = new char[64*1024];
   // а это такой конструктор:)
   B *b = new (buf) B ();

   b->addA(a);
   b->addA(c);

   b->func(2000);
   // вызываем явно деструктор
   b->~B();
   // и почистим за собой память
   delete[] buf;
   return 0;
}
```

Теперь код компилируется и похоже работает так, как ожидалось. Более того, там даже нет утечек и расстрелов памяти (я проверял valgrind).

Ещё раз - эта штука - сильно gcc'шная. Уже даже clang отказывается ее компилировать. Студийный компилятор такого не переносит также. **Стоит ли это использовать даже в домашних заданиях? нет.** Не стоит. Если только Ваш курс не называется "неочевидные и устаревшие возможности gcc".

Answer (score 3):

1. Размер массива должен быть известен на этапе компиляции. Поэтому данное объявление

   ```
   A *a[];
   ```

   не корректно.
2. Вы не можете применять оператор `delete []` к имени массива.
3. Массив не был распределен динамически.

   ```
   class B {
       A *a[];
       int index = 0;
   public:
       ~B() { delete[] a; }
       //..
   ```

Comment: Препод сказал, что в данном задании использовать такие массивы обязательно.

Comment: @justpainm8 Либо вы его не так поняли, либо он не прав.

Comment: Cпасибо. Значит, мне надо делать как то так?  `A* a[number];`?

Comment: @justpainm8 Да, только number должно быть константным выражением. И вы не можете удалять этот массив с помощью delete[] , а также не можете удалить его элементы, так как эти указатели не создаются объектом класса.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, препод ожидает чего-то более прозаического, например (отдельные строки)

```
A **a; // Нужен массив указателей? Объявим указатель на указатель
a = new A* [скольконибудь]; // создаем динамический массив указателей
delete[] a; // уничтожаем динамический массив в деструкторе
```

А если "скольконибудь" заранее неизвестно и надо массив растягивать (или даже сжимать), то придется создать новый, все что нужно в него переписать, старый уничтожить и т.п. Книжная такая задача.